# How to Report / or create a View on Profile Usage

Tags: reporting, administration, profile, custom-profile, view

I am in the process of consolidating the profiles in our Org.

I want to create a view / Report that shows me **all the profiles that have 5 or less users in them (including ones with no users assigned to them)**

Tried using custom reports types with 'Users' but no profile option is present...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using standard report but you can easily do this using APEX

```
Set<Id> ProfileId = new Set<Id>();
for(AggregateResult ar :[Select count(Id),ProfileId from User Group BY profileId])
        if(Integer.valueOf(ar.get('expr0')) > 5)
               ProfileId.add((ID)ar.get('ProfileId'));
List<profile> profileList = [Select Id from Profile WHERE ID NOT IN:ProfileId ];
System.debug(profileList);
```

In the `ProfileList` you will get name of all profile where user count is less then 5. Then you can easily display this result on Visualforce page.